# How to call method from class in service from c# unity code

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine

My problem is when i call my java code from c# in unity, i get null reference, but my class is 100% is not null. I have an idea that the problem is that my service is running on another process but i have not found any information about calling java methods which does not extends unityplayeractivity in class.

I tried to get my service instance and get needed class to call method, but it does not work. Also i tried to call method from my service. I get all 3 debugs in unity and null reference thrown after. Now my code looks like:

```
if (condition)
    {
        Debug.Log("1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111");
        AndroidJavaClass javaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.fileControllers.FileTransferService");
        Debug.Log("22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222");
        AndroidJavaObject controller = javaClass .GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("serverContactsMessagesController");
        Debug.Log("33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333");
        controller.Call("UnregisterRadio", id, cai);
    }
```

My FIleTransfer Class looks like:

```
package com.fileControllers;
public class FileTransferService extends Service  {
public static SIPMessageController serverContactsMessagesController;
public static FileTransferService Instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("TestManualDisconnect", "Starting file transfer service");
        Instance = this;
        serverContactsMessagesController = new SIPMessageController();
    }
}
```

My SIPMessageController class:

```
package com.fileControllers.SIPMessage;
public SIPMessageController()
{
    Start();
}
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    serverTextNotifications = new ServerMessagesHandler(FileTransferService.mContext);
    client = new UDPListener(m_port);
    client.start();
    listener = new SIPMessageListener();
    client.setMessageRecivedListener(listener);
    responseController = new SIPResponseController();
    //loginController = new ServerContactsMessagesController();
    Log.d("TestSIP", "Started sip messages controller");
}
```

And Unregister Method:

```
public void UnregisterRadio(int serverID, int CAI)
{
    Log.d("TESTTESTTEST", "UNREGISTERING RADIO");
    try {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    SIPRegistrationMessage message = new SIPRegistrationMessage(ExtensionTypes.Register);
    message.userName = "unregister";
    SIPHeader header = new SIPHeader(false, true, true, false, true);
    int reqNumber = new Random().nextInt(1000000);
    stream.write(header.Render());
    ConvertSIPData.WriteVarInt(stream, reqNumber);
    stream.write(message.Render());
    byte[] messageBytes = stream.toByteArray();
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(messageBytes, messageBytes.length, GetAccessuarByRadioID(serverID, CAI), m_port);
    client.Send(packet);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.d("Errors", "Error on Sending SIP message " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Don't think that error helps but:

```
E/Unity: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at UIChatMessages.ConnectToServer () [0x000bb] in <c21560bc798f49c3b4e266f4b3a67dd1>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () [0x00011] in <b6d510486de34305839d30de90e040c0>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00023] in <b6d510486de34305839d30de90e040c0>:0 
  at UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () [0x00027] in <64e28a9e74f14b82b76e6bb05ae2a678>:0 
  at UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) [0x00011] in <64e28a9e74f14b82b76e6bb05ae2a678>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) [0x00008] in <64e28a9e74f14b82b76e6bb05ae2a678>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1] functor) [0x00070] in
```

any solutions? now its working with activity which broadcasts method to my service, but i want to call service method from my c# code

Comment: Can u show us the code of the class AndroidJavaClass and AndroidJavaObject ?